# gitIgnore for .history angular project

Tags: angular, file, gitignore

Why is gitignore not working for me?
Why are files in .history folder not getting ignored?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make sure to remove those files from the index first:

```
git rm -r --cached src/.history/
```

Then check the status reported by VSCode: those files should not be there.

Note: the .gitignore rule should be

```
.history/
```

(no need for '`*`': you ignore the just the folder, with the trailing '`/`': that is enough)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your file structure looks like exactly, but it appears to me like you have the path to the `.history` directory wrong in your repository's `.gitignore` file.

From looking at the VCS pane, it appears to me like the path should be `src/.history/*`, instead of `.history/*`. Paths in `.gitignore`, and for Git in general, are relative to the base directory of the Git repository.

Comment: Then can you please share more information about your fine structure? It's not possible to tell from what you have listed currently.

Comment: Also, did you previously `git add` files in the `.history` folder?